# Pass paramater to webservice on ajax

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a simple web service with one argument :

```
public static string LoadComboNews(string id)
{
    string strJSON = "";
    DataRowCollection people = Util.SelectData("Select * from News where person = "+ id +" Order by NewsId desc ");
    if (people != null && people.Count > 0)
    {
        //temp = new MyTable[people.Count];
        string[][] jagArray = new string[people.Count][];

        for (int i = 0; i < people.Count; i++)
        {
            jagArray[i] = new string[] { people[i]["NewsID"].ToString(), people[i]["Title"].ToString() };
        }

        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        strJSON = js.Serialize(jagArray);
    }

    return strJSON;
}
```

on javascript I am trying to call it with parameter :

```
jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "webcenter.aspx/LoadComboNews",
        data: "{'id':usrid}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
            // Replace the div's content with the page method's return.
            combonews = eval(msg.d);
        }

    });
```

**UPDATE:**

usrid is  dynamic

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: What issue are you facing?

Comment: when I alert combonews there is nothing

Comment: @publicgk do I pass the parameters properly, is this the way we pass them on post?

Comment: The ajax request looks okay, except maybe: `"{'id':'" + usrid + "'}"`. But your C# function is static? Is it exposed as a webservice method?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think the problem is the quotes around 'id'.  Try changing it to "{id: usrid}" and see if that works.

Comment: @publicgk you are very correct, I actually was using it for pagemethods, but for some reasons jquery ajax id better for me

Comment: Your code is **VERY** susceptible to SQL Injection attacks. I strongly recommend using command parameters rather than dynamically generated SQL.

Comment: I always use bare json objects {id : userid} and it works fine.

Comment: THank you @p.s.w.g, can you send me some tutorial links about caommand parameters , thank You

Comment: @INgeeg Examples [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tyy0sz6b.aspx). More info on SQL injection [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648339.aspx) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

data you are sending is invalid `"{'id':usrid}"`

this not a valid json
probably what you wanna do is assuming usrid is a variable

```
"{\"id\":"+usrid+"}"
```

with it shoudnt you be executing this command

`Select * from News where person = '"+ id +"' Order by NewsId desc`

Considering id is a string

also try this

```
combonews = JSON.stringify(msg);
```

Comment: does the name can't we just omit the name id, and use directly usrid

Comment: no errors, just empty msgbox, if i run websirvice without parameters it works fine, but when it comes to [arameter, somehow it doesn't except

Comment: put a breakpoint to check that value of user id that you are sending from the js is reaching the server fine

Comment: Yes Parv Sharam you are right, but there is no output, I check the database , and the query give me some results

Answer (score 1):

Add WebMethod to the method

```
[WebMethod]
public static string LoadComboNews(string id)
```

And try this format

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "webcenter.aspx/LoadComboNews",
    data: '{"id":"usrid"}',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (msg) {
        // Replace the div's content with the page method's return.
        alert(msg.d);
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
        alert(textStatus + " " + errorThrown);
    }
});
```

Or

```
data: '{"id":"' + usrid + '"}',
```